# translation not working when added new store in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, translate

I already had 2 stores, translation was working fine in them, then I created another 3 stores and translated them from csv file, but the translation is not working. Magento2.3.2

**this is already had 2 stores and work well**

```
en_US.csv
it_IT.csv
```

**this is I created another 3 stores and translated but not working**

```
es_ES.csv 
fr_FR.csv 
ko_KR.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the locale for your newly created store

Follow below steps:

Go to: **Configuration > General > General > Locale Options**

Now select your **Scope website: Spain**

Open Locale Options tab and select Locale: `Spanish (Spain)` and Save Configurations

Change **Scope website: France**
Select Locale: `French (France)` and Save Configurations

Change **Scope website: South Korea**
Select Locale: `Korean (South Korea`)  and Save Configurations

**Run cache flush command and deploy command for all locales again flush cache**

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Upload the csv in this following path: **app/design/frontend/Theme/korean/i18n/**

Then run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

*You may need to add `-f` in option in you are in a developer env*